# Unity5: Objects in the scene are black. How am I able to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and yesterday I was playing with it(maybe I mistakenly did something wrong...) and now every time I put objects in the scene, it becomes like this. I am unable to solve this problem. Why is this happening though the game view is not affected?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqo7p.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top left corner of the Scene View, there is a little drop-down menu that says "Wireframe". This is the setting you are currently on; it allows people to more easily debug mesh information. Change it back to "Shaded" to get the view you want back.

Relevant link: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ViewModes.html

(I don't know why someone downvoted your question, I'll upvote it)